# meet syntax error while using limit clause in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL developer to do some query. I met unknown syntax error while using limit clause

```
select * from rpo_restriction_criteria
limit 5;
```

Then it states "syntax error, partially recognized rules (railroad diagrams)." Does anyone know how to solve the syntax error for limit clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there's no `limit` clause in Oracle.

Use e.g.

```
select * from rpo_restriction_criteria
fetch first 5 rows only;
```

or

```
select * from rpo_restriction_criteria
where rownum <= 5;
```